# Multiple Links/Text scrolling one after the other

Tags: scroll, marquee

I want to create a notification bar for my website, where I want multiple notifications to showcase on the top. If any one can help me to do this, Reference video attached below.

I tried marquee but only single line scrolling effect is possible, I am expecting multiple text to scroll one after the other.